# Different Views for Customer page and Engineering Page

Tags: 2007, infopath

I'm using an InfoPath form embedded in a webpart in a MOSS 2007 webpage. I'd like to have a Customer go to this page and see a certain view and not any of the others. After the form is submitted, the engineering team needs to be able to see the Team View, which has all the submitted information plus fields they will fill in.

I have these two views, and the single Customer view shows up by itself in the webpage because I turned off the toolbar that has view selection. But, that means that the engineering team can't see the Team View when they go to the form library.

My idea is to have a "Submitted_flag" variable and set this to FALSE. Then when the form is submitted, it will turn to TRUE. I'll have a button to switch to the Team View appear if the "Submitted_flag" variable is TRUE.

Is this the easiest way to do this or should I approach the problem another way?

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have the right idea.  You can also switch views based on users or groups, so you could just set the form to automatically switch to the engineering view on form load when an engineer opens it.  That eliminates an extra click.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do you control views depending on who is using the form?

Comment: Go to Tools --> User Roles to set up your groups/users (this will be the network id for the logged in user. Unfortunately AD groups and SharePoint groups won't work, but you can create a group for this form and put AD users in it.

After you have established these roles, go to Tools --> Form Options.  On the Open and Save category there is a "Rules" button in the Open Behavior section.  On the dialog that appears, set the Condition to "[User's current role] [is equal to] [the role you just created for engineers]".  Hit the Add action btn, choose the "Switch Views" action, select the eng view.

Comment: I ran out of characters and had to abbreviate near the end.  Hope it makes sense.  Good luck!